# Centre div vertically and horizontally in div

Tags: css

Trying to centre a div vertically and horizontally inside another div.

I have looked at most of the other questions, but they aren't working for me.

This needs to be responsive to screen size.  `.case_txt` is the inner div.

The code below centres `.case_txt` horizontally, but not vertically.

```
 .case_btn {
      width: 90%;
      height: 20%;
      background: #838383;
      border: 1px solid white;
      margin-bottom: 20%;
      padding: 0px;
    }

 .case_txt {
     margin: 0 auto;
     text-align: center;
     border: 1px solid red;
     color: white;
}
```

Comment: display:table-cell; on the parent and display:inline-block; on the child causes the parents (there are multiple divs with class case_btn) to be aligned next to each other instead of vertically..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I horizontally center an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-can-i-horizontally-center-an-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually haven't tried any vertical centering in your code. But anyhow … it's really easy with Grid or Flexbox. Maybe your issue was the `height: 20%` on the container? Better to use `vh` units.

```css
.case_btn {
  width: 90%;
  height: 40vh;
  background: #838383;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-bottom: 20%;
  padding: 0px;
  display: grid;
}

 .case_txt {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: white;
  place-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="case_btn">
  <div class="case_txt">Text Div</div>
</div>
```